# Display **Start or End Error Message** with dates values using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I just want to  display **Start or End Error Message** on my `msg` column with dates values using mysql

[image]

This is my query

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`start_date`,`end_date` FROM teams 
WHERE sub_cat_id = '84' AND  SYSDATE() > `start_date` AND SYSDATE() < `end_date` ORDER BY `id` DESC;
```

I am little much confuse about to display error messages then how do I track the Start and End date message?

[image]

If system date is greater than start date the message will be show **start** or the same scenario for end date the message will be show **end**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`start_date`,`end_date`, '' `error_message`
FROM teams 
WHERE sub_cat_id = '84' AND  SYSDATE() > `start_date` AND SYSDATE() < `end_date` 
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL `id`, NULL `name`, NULL `start_date`, NULL `end_date`, 
       CASE WHEN MIN(`start_date`)<SYSDATE() THEN 'Start'
            WHEN MAX(`end_date`)>SYSDATE() THEN 'End'
            WHEN COUNT(*)=0 THEN 'SubCat'
       END `error_message`
FROM teams 
WHERE sub_cat_id = '84' AND  
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM teams 
                  WHERE sub_cat_id = '84' AND  SYSDATE() > `start_date` AND SYSDATE() < `end_date`)
ORDER BY `id` DESC;
```

Comment: Thankx for sharing your experience

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou Mark Bannister for helping me

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`start_date`,`end_date`,
     CASE WHEN SYSDATE() < `start_date`  THEN 'WAITING'        
          WHEN SYSDATE() >= `start_date` AND SYSDATE() <= `end_date` THEN 'START'
          WHEN SYSDATE() >= `end_date`  THEN 'END'
    END `status`
FROM teams 
WHERE sub_cat_id = '84'
```